# MySQL - Unix timestamp from columns with hour, day, month

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysql-5.0

I have MySQL table with columns (day, month, hour). Is it possible to build unix timestamp from this within the query itself?

I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT unix(2016, a.month, a.day, a.hour, 00, 00) as d
FROM a
WHERE d > 456456 AND d < 789789
```

Values 456456 and 789789 is provided from an application. I know, I can create unix timestamp from `STR_TO_DATE`, but then I have to create it for every comparison in `WHERE` clause as well, which I am afraid will be slow.

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `data_a` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `hour` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `month` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;
```

MySQL version 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of transforming the columns in the `WHERE` clause, do so with the constants given by the application. Those calculations only have to be done once.

We can write the condition in a short, compact form:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(...)
FROM a 
WHERE  (2016, a.month, a.day, a.hour, 0, 0)
      >
      (  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)), 
        MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)),
          DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)),
         HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)),
       MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)),
       SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
      ) 
  AND  (2016, a.month, a.day, a.hour, 0, 0)
      <
      (  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)), 
        MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)),
          DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)),
         HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)),
       MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)),
       SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
      )
```

or in a long form, which has much more chances of using indexes effectively, in versions before 5.7:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(...)
FROM a 
WHERE ((2016 > YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
        AND a.month > MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
        AND a.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
        AND a.day > DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
        AND a.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
        AND a.day = DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))
        AND a.hour > HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(456456))))
AND   ((2016 < YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.month < MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.day < DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.day = DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.hour < HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789)))
    OR (2016 = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.day = DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND a.hour = HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))
        AND 0 < MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))+SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(789789))))
```

This will also allow MySQL to use indexes on this query, if available. If not already done, you should create an index as `(month, day, hour)` ([in this order!](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/optimization.html#multiple-column-indexes)).

Comment: You are right that to use indexes, the reverse transformation has to be done. But your transformation is not correct (i.e. equivalent). Since it seems you know that, why don't you edit and correct it so it works always and not in the limited case you mention (same day)?

Comment: @ypercube I now did, but didn't test it. You may want to look through it, whether you spot any errors in the logic.

Comment: No.  `FROM_UNIXTIME(456456)` is `1970-01-05 22:47:36`.  It would be coincidence if you get the correct `MONTH` from that.

Comment: "Index merge" is rarely used by the Optimizer.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for spotting this - `YEAR()` should also be compared to 2016, because that's an implicit assumption, that I made so far. It seems like the timestamps provided will only be of year 2016 though, because there is no `year` column in the table and OP specifically writes 2016 in their query.

Comment: I don't think that index merge is even relevant for this query. It's more relevant to [Row constructors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html) but there is no similar page in 5.0 docs so I'm not sure how it will behave. In any case, using AND/OR is probably better than the compact form.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I didn't know about that short form, very nice - to look at, at least! :)
I tried both queries on a testcase and the compact query took about 10x as long as the more complicated one - with the latter using multiple ranges on the full index and the compact one doing a full table scan. You're right - index merge is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Yeah, the compact form is nice but a problem with indexes. I think they corrected that in the latest 5.7 (or perhaps in the next, still in development release). Can't remember where I read it.

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(CONCAT('2016-', 5, '-', 31, ' ', 7, ':00:00') AS DATETIME);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(CONCAT('2016-', 5, '-', 31, ' ', 7, ':00:00') AS DATETIME) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-05-31 07:00:00                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, something like `CAST(CONCAT('2016-', month, '-', day, ' ', hour, ':00:00') AS DATETIME)`

Comment: How much difference is there between casting a string to datetime and using `STR_TO_DATE`?

Comment: It would probably work with just the `CONCAT`.

Comment: You don't need `CAST`, because OPs questions was targeting a unix timestamp as a result. So you would have to put the whole thing into a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` call, which takes a datetime string as an argument and does a string-to-timestamp conversion anyway. But that was not OPs question. OP wanted to know, whether there was any alternative to creating that unix timestamp for every row in the table for the `WHERE` part - and thus having to do a full table scan.

Comment: But since you posted your `CAST(CONCAT(...))` as an alternative to OPs `STR_TO_DATE` (which can do more string to datetime conversions than the cast), I wanted to know whether there were any difference between those two approaches in this case, that you had in mind.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE()` is a more complex function.  However, function time is usually insignificant compared to the time taken to fetch rows.  Mostly I wanted to bring out that it could be done in one line, not several.